# пул потоков с++

Tags: c++

Есть ли какая-то реализация пула потоков, чтобы они выполняли метод с разными входными параметрами. Объясняю. Допустим, есть вектор с ссылкам и 5 потоков. В векторе лежит одна единственная ссылка. Я хочу, чтобы один поток взял эту ссылку, скачал, нашёл на ней все ссылки, положил в этот же вектор и удалил исходные, а остальные потоки также брали б ссылки из этого вектора и делали ту же работу. Я пробовал некоторые пулы потоков, но у меня выходило так, что они все одновременно брали эту ссылку и в итоге выполняли одинаковую работу. Мне б хотелось, чтоб все потоки брали разные ссылки. Понимаю, что это скорее всего не самый простой способ написания краулера, но мне просто хочется реализовать эту идею, если это, конечно, возможно.

Comment: да все реализации пула потоков могут выполнять что-то с разными параметрами...

Comment: Вам не вектор, а потоко-безопасная очередь нужна. Гуглить по ключевым словам "concurrent queue" и "lock-free queue".

Answer (score 2):

Синхронизируйте доступ к разделяемым данным (в вашем случае это вектор, но лучше очередь или дек). После того как поток получил ссылку, удаляйте ее из вашей структуры данных и освобождайте блокировку. Также кешируйте обработанные ссылки в хеш-таблице или еще где-нибудь.